# apt-get sub-process returned an error code (1)

Tags: apache-2.2, apt, linode

I recently removed apache2 from my linode ubuntu server with:

```
apt-get --purge remove apache2
```

Then tried to install it again (`apt-get install apache2`). But since then, I can't use apt-get anymore, I get the following (resumed):

```
ERROR: Site default does not exist!
dpkg: error processing apache2.2-common (--configure):
dpkg: dependency problems are stoping apache2-mpm-worker of being configured
dpkg: dependency problems are stoping apache2 of being configured

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I remove apache2, apache2.2-common and apache2-mpm-worker everything works again, but I need apache installed!

Any ideias of what may be causing the errors?

PS: I translated the errors message, so they might be not entirely accurate

Comment: Do you have a longer error message?  There's usually something further up with more detail.

Comment: Here is the complete output of `apt-get install` http://pastebin.com/ZkB9PmQW

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you also manually have removed configuration files under /etc/apache2/? Note that those files belong to the package apache2.2-common, hence that being the package you need to make sure gets purged, not merely removed, before you can reinstall it.

Comment: Hi, how would I do that? `apt-get purge apache2.2-common` is enough? And yes, there's no /etc/apache2 anymore.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Once I did `apt-get install apache2` also installed (at least partially) apache2.2-common. So there're configurations files under /etc/apache2. Any ideias?